# how to share data from different accounts via my android app

Tags: android, facebook

I'm developping an android app and I want to post some data from my app on facebook. I can post data from my own account but i can't from a different account how can i fix that? Can anyone help?

Comment: Is your app in public mode?

Comment: no it s on development mode is it associated with my issue i know it allows the data being shown  on the people timeline

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your app is in development mode, then only people with admin/developer/tester roles can use your app. Either add them to those roles in your app settings, or set your app to public.